# Using jquery.slimscroll, the second init doesn't scroll anymore via mousewheel (with examples)

Tags: slimscroll

So I'm using jquery.slimscroll (https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll). When I load content and call .slimScroll, the script works as expected, when I load the content the second time, the content doesn't scroll anymore via mousewheel. I've created an example:

```
$("nav > ul#notificationList > li").hover(
            function () {
                GetNotifications();
            },
            function () {
                //ResetNewNotificationCount();
            });

function GetNotifications()
{

 var $notifications = $("nav > ul#notificationList > li > div");

 $notifications.empty();


  for(i=0; i<30; i++)
  {
      $notifications.append($("<div/>", {
                "class": "notification"
            }).append("<span>test test test test</span>"));
  }
  $("nav > ul#notificationList > li > div").slimScroll({
          height: "25em",
          width: "25em"
     });
}
```

If you hover over the bell, the content gets loaded, the scroll works, if you hover over the bell for after the first time, the content doesn't scroll anymore...

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5j58u9z8/5/

It seems like the onmousewheel eventhandler somehow gets destroyed (caused by the hover??)

Can anyone help me to get this resolved??

Comment: I created a simple jsfiddle and there it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cjLsp295/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to give the div where I loaded the notifications an Id;